# Sum up array with objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am having the following array with objects and I would like to sum up all occurrences of `watt`:

```js
let allProducts = [{
    "unique_id": "102",
    "currency": "$",
    "price": "529.99",
    "watt": 150
  },
  {
    "unique_id": "11",
    "currency": "$",
    "price": "323",
    "watt": 150
  },
  {
    "unique_id": "13",
    "currency": "$",
    "price": "23",
    "watt": 77
  }
]

let getWatt =
  _(allProducts)
  .map((objs, key) => ({
    'watt': _.sumBy(objs, 'watt')
  }))
  .value()

console.log(getWatt)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see I get back an array of `0` values. However, I would like to get back the result value of `377`. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's easy using plain js

```js
const sum = allProducts.reduce((a, {watt}) => a + watt, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script>
let allProducts = [{
    "unique_id": "102",
    "currency": "$",
    "price": "529.99",
    "watt": 150
  },
  {
    "unique_id": "11",
    "currency": "$",
    "price": "323",
    "watt": 150
  },
  {
    "unique_id": "13",
    "currency": "$",
    "price": "23",
    "watt": 77
  }
]


</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I've read the answers, but I'd like to add an explanation to your problem. The reason you're getting an array is because of using [**`.map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). As `map` returns you the array not a single element. Moreover, you are expecting to get the returned array as modified and `map` doesn't do that.

What you're trying to achieve is can be done using [**`.reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). I mean that's why `.reduce` is there

```js
let allProducts = [{
    "unique_id": "102",
    "currency": "$",
    "price": "529.99",
    "watt": 150
  },
  {
    "unique_id": "11",
    "currency": "$",
    "price": "323",
    "watt": 150
  },
  {
    "unique_id": "13",
    "currency": "$",
    "price": "23",
    "watt": 77
  }
];
var getWatt = allProducts.reduce((acc,curr)=> acc + curr.watt,0);
console.log(getWatt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take a single [`_.sumBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#sumBy) with the array of objects and the wanted key `watt` for summing.

Your attempt uses an object, instead of an array for `_.sumBy`. The object is not an array and the return value is zero.

```js
var allProducts = [{ unique_id: "102", currency: "$", price: "529.99", watt: 150 }, { unique_id: "11", currency: "$", price: "323", watt: 150 }, { unique_id: "13", currency: "$", price: "23", watt: 77 }],
    getWatt = _.sumBy(allProducts, 'watt');

console.log(getWatt)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
let allProducts = [{
    "unique_id": "102",
    "currency": "$",
    "price": "529.99",
    "watt": 150
  },
  {
    "unique_id": "11",
    "currency": "$",
    "price": "323",
    "watt": 150
  },
  {
    "unique_id": "13",
    "currency": "$",
    "price": "23",
    "watt": 77
  }
];

var sum = allProducts.reduce((sum,a)=>{
  return sum + a.watt;
},0);
console.log(sum);
```