# Calling function with a passed in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm trying to write a function that will be called with an array that has information on a person such as their name and then age. I need this function to grab all of the numbers only and then return them then added up. I've done some research and it seems filter and reduce are what I need to do this in the easiest way for a total beginner like me to do?

Apologies for any typos/wrong jargon as my dyslexia gets the better of me sometimes.
An example of what kind of array is being passed into the function when called;

```
  { name: 'Clarie', age: 22 },
  { name: 'Bobby', age: 30 },
  { name: 'Antonio', age: 40 },
```

Would return the total added numbers.
// returns 92

Why isn't the array I'm calling this function with working? Can you provide me a working example without the array being hardcoded like the other answers? - I'm passing in an array to the function. The main objective is to grab any number from the passed in array and add them together with an empty array returning 0.

```
function totalNums(person) {
  person.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
  return person.age;
}

console.log(totalNums([]))
```

Comment: The result of your `reduce` isn't captured. You'll need something like `const res = data.reduce((p, c) => p + c.age, 0)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum up array with objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670204/sum-up-array-with-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the result into a new variable then console.log() it like this

```
const arr= [{ name: 'Clarie', age: 22 },
  { name: 'Bobby', age: 30 },
  { name: 'Antonio', age: 40 },...
];

function totalNums(person) {
  let res = person.reduce((a,b) => a + b.age, 0)
  return res;
}

console.log(totalNums(arr));
```

and this is why it has to be like that

[.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

js methods like `.map()`, `.filter()`, `.reduce()` and some others, they return a new array, they don't modify the original array.
You can `console.log(arr);` and you will get this output:

```
    [{ name: 'Clarie', age: 22 },
      { name: 'Bobby', age: 30 },
      { name: 'Antonio', age: 40 },...
    ];
```

Your original array unchanged even after running your function so in order to get the result you expect, you need to store it inside a new variable

Comment: This has given me a lot to think on. Thank you, Chris!

Answer (score 3):

You need to save the result of your reduce.

For example with array of numbers you would do:

```js
function totalNums(person) {
  let res = person.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
  return res;
}

console.log(totalNums([5,6,4]))
```

And for your example you would like to do something like this:

```js
function totalNums(person) {
  let res = person.reduce((a,b) => a + b.age, 0)
  return res;
}

console.log(totalNums([ 
  { name: 'Clarie', age: 22 },
  { name: 'Bobby', age: 30 },
  { name: 'Antonio', age: 40 }
]))
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it in this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
function totalNums(person) {
  person.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
  return person.age;
}

console.log(totalNums([]))
```

Talking about the function you have created it is incorrect because:

- `return person.age;` Here you are passing an array to function and then accessing it like it's an object.
- `person.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)` you can't add `a` and `b` because `b` is an object.
- You are not storing value which `reduce` function will return.

### Solution Below :

The reduce function always returns something It never makes changes in the original array.

```
function totalNums(persons) {
  const totalAge = persons.reduce((total, person) => total + person.age, 0);
  return totalAge;
}

const persons = [
  { name: "Clarie", age: 22 },
  { name: "Bobby", age: 30 },
  { name: "Antonio", age: 40 },
];
console.log(totalNums(persons));
```

- You can replace `total` and `person` with `a` and `b` respectively in the above code snippet for your reference.